Integrate a function from -1 to 1
Create a function or program that takes any continuous, well-defined, single-input function (f(x)=...) and returns an approximate integration from -1 to 1. (at least 3 significant digits or more of precision)
Functions will be treated as programs, with arguments as inputs and returns as outputs.
As always, smallest byte length wins.
EXAMPLES:
y=x^2: ~0.6667
y=e^x: ~2.3504
y=πx^2+ex+1: ~4.0944
For languages where a function isn't a passable value (e.x. c, c++, etc.) the input function DOES NOT count towards character count.

“Well-defined” is not (well) defined :-). What exactly do you mean by that?

@LuisMendo well-defined function just means the function shouldnt depend on the domain and doesn't affect the code really

I believe some answers unavoidably fail case f(x)=max(0,1e10*(x-1+1e-10)). Can bound derivative to avoid

Yeah I’m not seeing how this can be done with full generality.  I feel like for any solution an adversarial input could be constructed

Python, 48 bytes
f=lambda y,p=1e5:p>-1e5and y(p/1e5)/1e5+f(y,p-1)

Attempt This Online!

NARS2000, 4 bytes
¯1(your function)∫1

Turns out a function isn't a passable value in NARS2000, but that just saves you a character according to OP. E.g. ¯1{⍵*2}∫1 counts as just ¯1∫1 — however, that's 8 bytes, as NARS2000 uses two bytes per character. If you want to pass a function in, you have to define an operator like {¯1⍺⍺∫1} and call it with a dummy argument.

@Adám thanks, I'll change that

JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes
Expects a single-argument function f(x){...}
I=f=>(Array(2e+3).fill``.map(n=>s+=f(i+=1e-3),s=0,i=-1)|s)*1e-3

Explanation:
I=f=>                  // define a function, I
  (
    Array(2e+3).fill`` // create an array with 2000 elements
    .map(              // use the array as a REPEAT n TIMES loop
      n=>s+=f(i+=1e-3),// add sample to sum, increment i by dx
      s=0,             // initialize sum
      i=-1             // start at -1
    )|s                // return sum, not the array

  )*1e-3               // multiply by dx


Try it online!

39 bytes But does it really give 3 correct decimal places?

I recommend holding off for a week on answering your own challenges, especially if doing so using a popular language.

Makes sense! Will do in the future!

APL+WIN 31 bytes
Prompts for function as a string and uses 10001 intervals for the numerical integration.
x←((0,⍳1E5)÷5E4)-1⋄⍎'2E¯5×+/',⎕

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic
